# "something replaced with a company's design" single word

Tags: single-word-requests

I am a design engineer, and I sometimes take some reference designs and replace some sections with our own customized designs. I need a single word to indicate the "**our own** design". Something like *Legendary* design. I need to say it as "*design completed and xxx section replaced with legendary (for example) design.*

Comment: It is not clear to me what it is you need. Is _Legendary_ the name of your company? Are you looking for something like "replaced with Legendary-made design"?

Comment: _Legendary_ is not my company name. i'm looking for something like the later question of yours.

Comment: You already got one idea, two in fact: "own design"; "custom design" -- not happy?

Comment: I don't get it . Which of the following is closest to what you want? *'Design completed and xxx section replaced with....       (1).... [design that is not ours but that we use a lot] ----- (2)....[design that is ours, we use often, but we have no patent on it] ------- (3)....[design that is ours, we did it specially for you]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your point, but "proprietary" is commonly used in the automobile industry for these contexts. For example, a shock absorber is a part used on every automobile, but every company which is in the business of manufacturing shock absorbers takes inputs from the automobile manufacturer and gives them a specially designed "proprietary" part.

Comment: you got  it brother... but "proprietary" is used to mention something with ownership right? we dont have ownership. we just use our own design instead of using their design. that's it.

Answer (score 0):

"Our" does not fit the bill for some reason?

then maybe:

- "Corporate" ?
- "Usual" ?
- "Conventional" ?
- "Routine" ?
- "Customary" ?
- "Common" ?
- "Stock" ?
- "Plain" ?
- "Vanilla" ?
- "Generic" ?
- "Familiar" ?
- "General" ?

Comment: What we need is the exact opposite of those.